# Why parent class may not be protected? (Java)

Tags: java, oop, protected

I am not sure why in a context like the following

```
class Parent {

    private void method1() {
        System.out.println("Parent's method1()");
    }


    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("Parent's method2()");
    }   

}


public class Child extends Parent {

    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("Child's method1()");                
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Parent p = new Child();
        p.method2();
    }

}
```

**Parent** may be package private, but not protected.

Specifically the error generated is

> modifier protected not allowed here

Which would *seem* to indicate that it is an issue of access privilege - but I am suspicious that this may be a red herring. `Private` modifier also generates an error (naturally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, Top level classes can have only package private and public modifiers.

Making a class `private` doesn't make any sense. If no one use that class for any reason, then why we need that class?

`protected` access modifier means, only visible within the enclosing class and any subclasses, and also anywhere in the enclosing class's package. No body knows which classes going to be subclass of a protected class. So, it also doesn't make sense

But both private and protected can be (and frequently are) applied to nested classes and interfaces, just never top-level classes and interfaces

Comment: Top-level classes, to be exact. Nested classes may be protected or private.

Comment: Just a note, this doesn't apply for inner classes.

Comment: Oh yes, it makes sense to not allow private on top-level classes; but any particular reason why protected on top-level is prohibited?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the protected access modifier for top level classes.

according to the [spec $8.1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1)

> The access modifier public (§6.6) pertains only to top level classes (§7.6) and to member classes (§8.5), not to local classes (§14.3) or anonymous classes (§15.9.5).
>
> The access modifiers protected and private (§6.6) pertain only to
>   member classes within a directly enclosing class or enum declaration
>   (§8.5).